# The square of Sorgenfrey line is not normal

Tags: general-topology

> **Statement**
>
> The square of the Sorgenfrey line is not normal
>
> *Proof*. Let be $\mathcal{L}_S$ the Sorgenfrey line. So since the euclidean topology $\mathcal{T}_e$ is such that $\mathcal{T}_e\subseteq\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{L}_{S}}$ it result that $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{L}_{S}}$ is normal and $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathcal{L}_S$, thus $\mathcal{L}_S$ is separable and so too $\mathcal{L}_S\times\mathcal{L}_S$. Now we remember that if $X$ is a normal and separable space such that contains a discrete and closed subspace Y such that $|Y|=k$, then $2^k\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ (this result is known as Jones' lemma). So we observe that the subset $\mathcal{D}:=\{(x,-x):x\in\Bbb{R}$} is a closed and discrete subspace such that $\mathcal{D}=2^{\aleph_0}$, thus by Jones' lemma $\mathcal{L}_S\times\mathcal{L}_S$ is not normal.

So I don't understand why $\mathcal{D}$ is discrete: infact we have that $|\mathcal{D}|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Discrete does not mean countable, but that each element in the set has an open neighborhood that contains only this element.

Comment: Yes, I know this. To be more accurate we can claim that a subset $Y$ of some topological space is discrete iff $Y$ is a set of isolated point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathcal{D}$ is discrete because for any $x$, the set $U_x:=[x,x+1) \times [-x,-x+1))$ is an open neighbourhood of $(x,-x)$ in $\mathcal{L}_S \times \mathcal{L}_S$ and it intersects $\mathcal{D}$ in $\{(x,-x)\}$, so all its points are isolated (this intersection is open in the subspace topology by definition).

That $\mathcal{D}$ is closed is clear; it's already closed in the coarser Euclidean topology on the plane.

The final contradiction comes from the fact that Jones' lemma implies $2^{2^{\aleph_0}} \le 2^{\aleph_0}$ which flat-out contradicts Cantor's theorem that for any cardinal $k$, $k < 2^k$.

Comment: I know it's super late but could you explain why $\mathcal{D}$ is closed? @HennaBrandsma

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory I do so in the answer.

Comment: I think, I failed to catch that. Maybe $\mathcal D$ didn't contain any limit point, which means it's vacuously satisfied closed criterion. Is that the case? @HennaBrandsma

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory that’s one way to see it. $D$ is more easily seen to be closed in the usual topology on the plane so it’s still closed here.

Comment: Aha, I forgot that an isolated point is closed (and $\mathcal D$ is discrete). Thanks, @HennaBrandsma for your quick response.